# HAVING distance Greater than and Less than in the same Query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT city, (6372.797 * acos(cos(radians({$latitude})) * cos(radians(`latitude_range`)) * cos(radians(`longitude_range`) - radians({$longitude})) + sin(radians({$latitude})) * sin(radians(`latitude_range`)))) AS distance FROM cities WHERE active = 1 HAVING distance > 25 ORDER BY distance ASC
```

I like to be able to grab all cities `HAVING` a distance greater than 25KM and less than 50KM. Anything I try entering either results in all cities greater than 25KM or an error.

How does one go about adding `HAVING distance > 25 AND distance <= 50` to my SQL query?

Answer (score 8):

Exactly the way that you have in the question:

```
SELECT city, (6372.797 * acos(cos(radians({$latitude})) * cos(radians(`latitude_range`)) * cos(radians(`longitude_range`) - radians({$longitude})) + sin(radians({$latitude})) * sin(radians(`latitude_range`)))) AS distance
FROM cities
WHERE active = 1
HAVING distance > 25 and distance <= 50
ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Just as a small note:  the use of the `having` clause to filter on column aliases (like `distance`) is a MySQL extension.  In most databases, you would have to use a subquery.

Comment: I thought it would be this as well. If I use `distance > 25` on its own I get all cities greater than 25 KM. When I introduce the second half - even what you showed above I get zero results.

Comment: Skip that - got it figured out. It does work, the longitude that was being passed was missing the minus sign at the beginning.

Comment: Any idea how we could compare to another field in  the table?  making the 25 and 50 dynamic? thanks!

Comment: @Notflip . . . You would put the column names in place of the constants.  If you want a question, you should ask as a question and not in a comment.

Comment: Hi Gordon! Thank you, this is my open question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438137/laravel-own-variable-in-scope