# Laravel own variable in scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm using the haversine formula to calculate a distance, **this is working fine.**

> But I would like to hide results where the distance is greater then the max_radius field on that result.

This is my database scheme.

[image]

This is the query I'm using. 
**You can see I hard coded the distance (50)**

```
public function scopeFitsDistance($query, $lat, $lng)
{
    return $query->select(\DB::raw("*,
                      ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                        cos( radians( lat ) )
                        * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                        ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                        sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                      ) AS distance"))
            ->addBinding($lat, 'select')
            ->addBinding($lng, 'select')
            ->addBinding($lat, 'select')
            ->having('distance', '<', 50); <----------
}
```

But now I'm wondering how I can hide results where that distance < max_radius, which is a field inside the table.

### The following returns no results

```
->having('distance', '<', 'max_radius');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` only works with `GROUP BY`

You can do a sub-select and then use a `WHERE` clause instead.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample please? I'm not sure if I know how to implement a sub-select. thank you!